# Installing rpy2 on windows, "no R home is found"

Tags: rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 on windows 8, but I keep getting the following error:

> Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.

I've put the path to R home, R.exe, and R.dll in the environmet variables but the same error is appearing. I am using Python version 2.7.

Any workaround?

Comment: `conda install rpy2` works perfectly. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem on windows, R Version 3.3.1 and Python 2.7. 
What helped me was using the Windows-Binaries instead of trying the traditional way with pip

```
pip install rpy2
```

Instead go to:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2
and download the suiting whl file for your configuration. Then go to your download folder in cmd and simply use:

```
pip install rpy2-2.7.8-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Note, make sure you adapt this code to your download file.

Comment: Thank you bro! Helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to plague Pythonistas -- and there is no one clear single solution. An important cause of the error report is failure to ensure that the version of R you have installed on your machine is Version 2.8.0 or greater. Python 2.7 seems to be able to manage it. The other answers about using easy_install and setting env variables all are important but secondary to having a working version of R.